# How do I get the place holders in msword to be replaced with user entered values using python?

Tags: python, user-interface

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

document_path = Path(file).parent / "MS.docx"
doc = DocxTemplate(document_path)

today = datetime.datetime.today()
today_in_one_week = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Service engineer"),sg.Input(key="Service engineer")],
    [sg.Text("STATION NAME"),sg.Input(key="STATION")],
    [sg.Text("PRODUCT ID"),sg.Input(key="ID")],

    [sg.Button("Read"),sg.Exit()],
]

window = sg.Window("MSI SERVICE ", layout , element_justification="right")

while True:
    event,values=window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event =="Exit":
        break
    if event == "Read":
        print(event,values)
        values["TODAY_IN_ONE_WEEK"]= today_in_one_week.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        values["TODAY"]= today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        doc.render(values)

        output_path = Path(file).parent/ "msi.docx"
        doc.save(output_path)
        sg.popup("FILE SAVED", f"file has been saved here : {output_path} ")

window.close()
```

i have this code but it dosent create the new ms word file when i run it. it prints the info i enter in GUI in console so i know the values are going in but why cant i get the new ms word file
i tried to do it with a smaller program where i hard coded what has to go without GUI and the ms word had the value instead of the place holder

Comment: Try to reduce your code to only about docxtpl library, maybe only 10 lines for it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).